# Does a Riemannian submersion maps horizontal geodesics to geodesics, and a relevant question?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Setup:**

Let $\pi:(M,g)\to (N,h)$ be a surjective *Riemannian* submersion,

- i.e. $\forall p\in M, D\pi_p$ is surjective between the respective tangent spaces and that .
- $T_pM=H_pM \oplus V_pM$ ($g_p$-orthogonal direct sum), and
- $H_pM$  is isometric to $T_qN, q:=\pi(p)$ via $D\pi_p, i.e. h_q(D\pi_p(v), D\pi_p(w)=g_p(v,w)\forall v,w \in H_pM.$ (this defines the Riemannian submersion part, isometry of the horizontal part of the tangent space with the tangent space of the image/quotient).

**Questions:**

1. **Is it true that $\pi$ maps *horizontal* geodesics in $M$ to geodesics in $N?$** Perhaps relevant is this MO question: [initially horizontal geodesics are always horizontal](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435401/initially-horizontal-geodesic-is-always-horizontal). I can't help thinking the way we show that an isometry $\phi$ maps geodesics to geodesics: the idea is to show for vectore fields $X,Y$ that $\phi_{*}(\nabla^M_X {Y})= \nabla^N_{\phi_{*}X}{\phi_{*}Y}.$ (John Lee: Riemannian manifolds: an introduction to curvature, P.71). **Should we show the same here for $X, Y$ hotizontal vector fields?**
2. **Is it true that $\forall v \in H_pM, exp^N_q(D\pi_p(v))= \pi(exp_p^M(v)),$ where $exp^M, exp^N$ represent the corresponding exponential maps?** I think this can be proven if 1) is proved, and noting that the initial velocity of the geodesic (if 1) is proven) $t\mapsto \pi(exp_p^M(tv))$ is indeed $D\pi_{p}(v),$ and then using the uniqueness of geodesic with initial point and initial velocity.

UPDATE: I just asked [the question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467304/does-a-riemannian-submersion-maps-horizontal-geodesics-to-geodesics-and-a-relev), as I haven't received a response yet. If requested, I can certainly delete one of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the horizontal lifts of $N$-geodesics are $M$-geodesics if $\pi: M\to N$ is a Riemannian submersion. And yes, a Riemannian submersion commutes with the geodesic flow in horizontal directions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but my question 1) was slightly different, it was asking for a proof that projection of horizontal $M$-geodesics are $N$-geodesics. If the proof is long, can you at least outline it or cite a resource that prove it? I'd like to see the proof technique.

Comment: I will try to think of a conceptual proof.  In the meantime, you can certainly consult a textbook for such basic facts.  @LearningMath  Your question 1 is not different, because by uniqueness of the geodesic with given initial conditions, a horizonal $M$-geodesic is exactly the same thing as a horizontal lift of an $N$-geodesic.